# How to truncate/span date to an interval?

Tags: java, date, java-8, java-time

I tried to truncate dates using Instant.truncatedTo but it seems it doesn't allow truncating more than one day duration. What I want to do is to truncate dates using a specific time interval. For example:

```
For 1hour interval, 2014-10-18T11:30:52.560Z should become: 2014-10-18T11:00:00.000Z 
For 1day interval, 2014-10-18T11:30:52.560Z should become: 2014-10-18T00:00:00.000Z 
For 1month interval, 2014-10-18T11:30:52.560Z should become: 2014-10-01T00:00:00.000Z 
For 6month interval, 2014-10-18T11:30:52.560Z should become: 2014-07-01T00:00:00.000Z
```

Therefore it's more like spaning the dates to a specific time interval.

I was actually using timestamp values in order to divide them by timestamp intervals ((dateTimestamp/intervalTimestamp)*intervalTimestamp) but when using months, there is no fixed timestamp values because the days of months may change so it doesn't work for months.

Comment: I think for 6 month interval you'll want 2014-07-01T00:00:00.000Z

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own function:

```
public LocalDateTime truncateTo(LocalDateTime dt, Time interval) {
    switch(interval) {
    case MONTH_6:
        if(dt.getMonthValue() > 6)
            dt = dt.withMonth(7);
        else
            dt = dt.withMonth(1);
    case MONTH:
        dt = dt.withDayOfMonth(1);
    case DAY:
        dt = dt.withHour(0);
    case HOUR: 
        dt = dt.withMinute(0);
        dt = dt.withSecond(0);
        dt = dt.withNano(0);
    break;
    }
    return dt;
}
```